# Automatically adjusting the brightness on battery

Tags: 18.04, brightness

Recently I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 and really happy with it.

I would like to decrease the brightness when running on battery and increase the same when connected to an external power supply. I checked the settings and there was no option. It can be done manually, but I am looking for an automated way of doing it.

Any script or an application would really help.